Active Directory multiple search from base dn
I have users in multiple domains.
For example:
DC=domain,DC=local; - (main domain) DC=department1,DC=domain,DC=local; - (subdomain1) DC=department2,DC=domain,DC=local; - (subdomain2)
There is a group in the main domain called group1 and some users in the subdomain are in this group.
If I want to get a list of users in group 1 via php, only users in the main domain will be visible. Users in the subdomain will not be visible.
How can I get a list of all users in group1.
This is my code in php:
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

set_time_limit(30);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

$ldaphost = "ldap://domain.local";
//Порт
$ldapport = "389";

$ldap = ldap_connect($ldaphost,$ldapport) or die('Cannot connect to LDAP Server.');
//Включаем LDAP протокол версии 3
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3) or die('Unable to set LDAP protocol version');
//Отключаем обработку рефералов для ldap v3
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0) or die('Unable to set LDAP OPT REFERRALS');

if ($ldap) /* Получаем данные из AD */
{
    $ldapuser      = 'ldap_system';  
    $ldappass     = '123456';

    $bind = ldap_bind($ldap,$ldapuser,$ldappass);
    if ($bind) //Привязка LDAP прошла успешно!
    {
        $query = ldap_search($ldap,"DC=domain,DC=local","(&(memberOf=CN=group1,OU=PQ185,OU=testGroups,DC=domain,DC=local)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))");

        // Read all results from search
        $data = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $query);
        // Loop over 
        $userdata = array();
        for ($i=0; $i < $data['count']; $i++) {
            array_push(
                $userdata, array(
                    'i' => $i,
                    'displayname' => $data[$i]['displayname'][0],
                    'samaccountname' => $data[$i]['samaccountname'][0],
                    'description' => $data[$i]['description'][0]
                )
            );
        }
        $json = json_encode($userdata);

        echo $json;
    }
}


The regular directory of each domain only knows about objects belonging to that domain.
If all domains belong to the same forest, try to query the Global Catalog directory that the domain controllers also provide. It works via LDAP the same way as the regular directory, except on ports 3268/3269 instead of the regular 389/636, and while it knows about all user accounts across the entire forest, it only has partial data for them – some attributes might be missing from the GC.
<?php
$ldap = ldap_connect("ldap://$host:3268");
ldap_set_option...
ldap_sasl_bind($ldap); /* for Kerberos authentication */

Not all AD domain controllers are GC servers; you should use DNS SRV records to find them:
<?php
$res = dns_get_record("_ldap._tcp.gc._msdcs.example.com", DNS_SRV); // new
$res = dns_get_record("_gc._tcp.example.com", DNS_SRV); // old
$urls = array_map(fn($r) => "ldap://{$r["target"]}:{$r["port"]}", $res);

